# c++ error: change from command line input to variable input

Tags: c++

I want to change from command line input to variable input.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << argc << std::endl;
    std::cout << argv[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Change to this, but when I want to compile this an error appears.

```
int main()
{
    int argc = 2;

    char *argv[] = 0;

    argv[0] = "./server";
    argv[1] = "127.0.0.1";
}
```

This error appears: error: array initializer must be an initializer list
    char *argv[] = 0;

Comment: `argv` is an array, not a pointer. `int foo[] = 0;` would also be an error.

Comment: Programming by guessing doesn't work. Pick up [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648) and study it carefully

Comment: What did you intend for the line `char *argv[] = 0;` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the size of the array, since you did not provide an initializer from which the compiler can deduce the size. Again, from C++11 you cannot have a *string-literal* bind to `char*`, use `const char*`.

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int argc = 2;
    const char *argv[argc] = {};

    argv[0] = "./server";
    argv[1] = "127.0.0.1";
}
```

You may want to explore good use of `std::array<std::string, 2>` instead.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, my oversight. Fixed. Thanks.